# BigQuery Standard SQL SELECT rows WHERE field contains words from another table field

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, sql-like

I have 2 tables in BigQuery.  VIDEOS table contains video names and tags.  CREATORS table contains information about video creators. The VIDEOS.tags field contains comma separated quoted strings.

I need to select all the videos that were tagged with names in the CREATORS table with results looks like this:

```
Title 1, Creator 1
Title 2, Creator 2
Title 3, Creator 2
Title 4, Creator 3
Title 5, Creator 3
...
```

But what I have below does not return any results in BigQuery.

```
SELECT
    B.name AS Title,
    C.creator_name AS Creator
FROM `project.database.VIDEOS` AS B, `project.database.CREATORS` AS C
WHERE B.tags LIKE CONCAT('%"', C.creator_name ,'"%')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such cases it  is usually because of differences in cases - try

```
WHERE LOWER(B.tags) LIKE CONCAT('%"', LOWER(C.creator_name) ,'"%')
```

Comment: wow, this exactly what was happening!  videos were tagged with lower cased names and genre.  I was staring at the tables for hours and did not realized it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want it the other way around: The tag has to look like the name. Let me know

```
SELECT
    B.name AS Title,
    C.creator_name AS Creator
FROM `project.database.VIDEOS` AS B, `project.database.CREATORS` AS C
WHERE C.creator_name LIKE CONCAT('%"', B.tags ,'"%')
```

Comment: This is not the case because the Creators table only contain the name of the studios or brands while the Videos table include tag fields that include creators as well as genres, event names, and keywords.